# How does Windows/AD/LDAP identify the user who is logging on?

Tags: windows, login, active-directory, authentication, ldap

I need to capture some AD login details from a user. I need to validate that the user has entered valid credentials, and lookup some attributes (email, etc.) for that user account.

I have no idea and also don't care what type of 'username' they enter, it could be a fully qualified samAccountName, just samAccountName on it's own, UPN, or something else: as long as AD says it's valid them I'm happy.

My issue is that once I get this far, what is the best way of figuring out **which** user just logged in? As in, how will I know which LDAP record to lookup the attributes from? If I knew I captured a samAccountName I could perform an LDAP query for:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(samaccountname={0}))
```

But I don't know what I have, it might be a samaccountname it might not. It could be anything. I could build up a massive query searching every possible attribute for the 'username' they entered, but that feels a bit wrong...

When you login to Windows 10 with a domain account, it looks up your firstname/lastname and shows that on the progress screen when logging in. How exactly does it do that? Is there a function I can call on the ldap connection to ask what the DN of the user that authenticated is? Or does the windows login screen have an inbuilt LDAP filter that it uses which I could copy?

Comment: You will have to make up your mind on what kind of information you expect and communicate it to the user. If in doubt let him indicate it using a checkbox. From what you're writing it sounds like you want to do this for arbitrary users. If it is the currently logged in users there is a wide variety of interfaces available that would get you that information. It would depend on the language.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those are possible in this case. This is going to be an application that's used in a massive organisation that has many different logon 'standards' which each dictate something different for certain users. This query is also going to be used before the machine is joined to the domain and before any domain user has logged in.. Windows login is able to do it, why can't I :-)

Comment: No, Windows isn't able to do it either. They don't expect arbitrary input that might be anything to do something. They very precisely know which formats they expect and how to handle them and as I said it's easy to rely on the credentials of the currently logged in user. But checking arbitrary input for whenever or not it could maybe in some form identify an actual object within AD is just nonsense.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to know - what formats does windows expect and how does it handle each of them? Is it just samaccountname & upn or are there others? How does it then identify the user that logged in, is it with the equivalent of an LDAP search or does it do an extended LDAP request (whoami) or something? I'm not saying I want my code to accepts anything, I would like whatever works in the windows login box to work in mine.

Comment: P.S. there is no currently logged in domain user. The current logged in user is a local administrator account. We need to lookup a domain user.

Answer (score 0):

[User Name Formats on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx) details what formats are expected. In short there are only two expected formats. Either `DOMAIN\user` or `user@domain`. Windows does it's thing by using the appropriate APIs which might differ per application if they're written in different languages.

As you expect the user to type in the name it should be obvious what you're looking for just as you might ask for credentials which again should make it obvious who is dong the request. If you allow anonymous lookups that are triggered from a general account you won't be able to identify who (physically) is doing the lookup.